# JavaScript: How to reduce functions?

Tags: javascript

How to reduce bellow 4 functions into one?
How to create a single scope for the bellow function in order to work.

```
var ele;
var ele1;
var ele2;
var ele3;
var ele4;
function Myfunction(obj) { 
    ele=document.getElementById(obj).style; 
    if(ele.display=="none") { 
        ele.display="block"; 
        ele1.display="none";
        ele2.display="none";
        ele3.display="none";
    }
    else { ele.display="none"; } 
}
```

How to create a single scope for the bellow function in order to work.

```
function Myfunction1(obj1) { 
    ele1=document.getElementById(obj1).style; 
    if(ele1.display=="none") { 
        ele1.display="block";
        ele.display="none";
        ele2.display="none";
        ele3.display="none";
    } 
    else { ele1.display="none"; } 
}
```

How to create a single scope for the bellow function in order to work.

```
function Myfunction2(obj2) { 
    ele2=document.getElementById(obj2).style; 
    if(ele2.display=="none") { 
        ele2.display="block";
        ele.display="none";
        ele1.display="none";
        ele3.display="none";
    } 
    else { ele2.display="none"; } 
}
```

How to create a single scope for the bellow function in order to work.

```
function Myfunction3(obj3) { 
    ele3=document.getElementById(obj3).style; 
    if(ele3.display=="none") { 
        ele3.display="block";
        ele.display="none";
        ele2.display="none";
        ele1.display="`enter code here`none";
    } 
    else { ele3.display="none"; } 
}
```

Comment: Update your question. The code examples and question are not clear. Put them in one code example.

Comment: What do want exactly? What is the initial value of `ele`, `ele1`, `ele2`, `ele3`? Do you want to show just one at the time like an accordion?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it all in one function,

first add a class to all elements `commonClass` you can change this name according to your feature.

Now create a function and pass id of elements.

```
function Myfunction(obj) { 
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".commonClass");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.querySelector("#"+obj).style.display = "block";
}
```

Although many way to do it, but its simple to understand you.